# Why does the MSTest accessor file contain a "desktop" reference

Tags: mstest, accessor

I am using VS2010 to create a new unit test project to test my solution. After I created the unit tests, the VS created a .accessor file. I know it is used to help test the private or protect members. But I opened the .accessor file, I found the file contain two line text, just like below format:

MyProjcet.dll

Desktop

I don't know why the Desktop reference is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the thread [Best practices trying to use the same unit test on desktop & device](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ccb12cca-2359-429b-8d8c-88cb7f0b2192/best-practices-trying-to-use-the-same-unit-test-on-desktop-device?forum=vststest):

It explains that this is a setting for a Desktop device (rather than a mobile one)